# How to deploy a .NET Core app to a local file share with azure pipelines?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I have WPF .NET Core and ASP.NET Core apps that I would like to deploy using azure pipelines.  My WPF app is deployed through a local file share, and my ASP.NET Core site is deployed on a local IIS server.

What options do I have in deploying these apps using azure pipelines?  Is a private agent the only way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that is the only option but it is probably the preferred option. Is there a reason you don't want to use a private agent?

Comment: @Crowcoder just setup and configuration time.  It can be done, just was curious if there were other options, like gateways or something like such that I could use to easily automate deployment without having to setup a private agent.

Comment: I imagine you could leverage Azure File Shares to make it happen but I don't see it being faster or easier, and it could introduce security issues.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to try out ssh task mentioned in below answer. How did it go?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I unfortunately have not got the chance to try it out, but that does answer my question and gives me some options.  I'll mark it as best answer.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using private agent, Another way to deploy your WPF app to local file share is to use Remote copy tasks to copy the WPF app from the cloud agent machine to your local file share.

You can use [Copy files over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops). This task allows you to connect to a remote machine using SSH.

Before using this task, you need to create SSH service connection to connect to your local file share machine. In your azure devops project portal, Go the **Project settings** --> **Service connections** under **Pipelines** -->**New service connection** and choose **SSH**. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information.

[image]

You can also check out [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops). The main idea is to create a connection between the microsoft cloud agents with your local file share. So that your local file share is accessible from the cloud agents.